# DevExpress: ширина GridView

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, devexpress

Каким образом (установкой параметра) в С# сделать так, чтобы при увеличении пользователем ширины одного из столбцов крайний правый не "уезжал" вправо за пределы видимой области?

Answer (score 0):

Запретить увеличивать ширину колонки если суммарная ширина всех колонок равняется ширине грида нельзя. Но грид умеет автоматически изменять ширину остальных колонок, чтобы уместить все колонки в видимой области.

Для того, чтобы ширина остальных колонок автоматичеки подстраивалась под ширину грида, установите [GridView.OptionsView.ColumnsAutoWidth](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridOptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth) в `true`.

Comment: Как же нельзя, когда можно... только не могу найти как это сделать. В чужой программе я это вижу!!!

Comment: Есть возможность сделать видео? Со слов я мог не верно представить ожидаемый резульат.